# Call to undefined function base_url()

Tags: codeigniter

I get this error when I try to load base_url funcion. The problem is that I've already added base_url to autoload file but the issue still:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

views/home.php file has the following code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <a href="<?= base_url()?>">Link</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas? Since base_url function is being loaded by autoload I don't know what else should I try to do to fix this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be that your not echoing the base_url

Try this

```
<?php echo base_url();?>
```

Instead of

```
<?= base_url()?>
```

As you have shown you are all ready auto loading url helper

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Make sure in CI3 versions base_url is not empty in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';
```

Wamp

```
www > project >
www > project > application 
www > project > system
www > project > index.php
```

Xampp

```
htdocs > project >
htdocs > project > application 
htdocs > project > system
htdocs > project > index.php
```

### Update: with the code you have provide in link

--

There were many bugs. I would start of will a fresh copy.

1: In your autoload.php you had two `$autoload['helpers'] = array();` I removed the empty one and worked. Where line **85 and 93** remove that and you will see on line **42** there is same.

2: In your config.php this `$config['index_page'] = 'home.php';` should be `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`

3: Your controller filesnames did not have there first letter uppercase.

Filename Home.php

```
<?php 

class Home extends CI_Controller {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The issue still and base_url isn't empty:
[code]$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/application/';[/code]

[code]<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>">Link</a>[/code]

Comment: When you have base_url you should name it like `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';` not the application folder

Comment: I translated the folder just for the example code, actually it's `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/aplicacion/';` so it should work in this way but it isn't.

Comment: @Claudio I have updated my answer with the folder structure I would not use application folder in your `http://localhost/aplicacion/`

Comment: I've changed the folder to "blog" but the error still there. I've uploaded the folder so you can check the code since I've followed many tutorials and can't find what's the problem.
[link](https://mega.nz/#!2YgXjbrS!e5vs_GTDBaSAJ7UPnLKRmpuhaQ8XByx8yGPhsUG92IQ)

Comment: Well, it works with `<a href="<?php echo $this->config->base_url(); ?>">Home</a>` but doesn't work with
`<a href="<?= base_url()?>">Home</a>`

Comment: I have found the issue for you will update my answers shortly

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It is working after made the changes you mentioned.
Could you please let me know why `$config['index_page'] = 'home.php';` is wrong? I set home.php since I have home.php file instead of index.php

Comment: Your welcome don't forget to accept answer by clicking on tick.

Comment: It is there for the urls. But if you want clean urls then make it blank. and have a htaccess. https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: Have a good read through here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/index.html and https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html

Comment: @Claudio why change from accepted answer to  unaccepted answer? Base url it to on my answer?

Comment: didn't know previous accepted answer was marked as unaccepted. Sorry! 2nd time using stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Change `<a href="<?= base_url()?>">Link</a>` with `<a href="<?=base_url()?>">Link</a>`. Do not add space when you are using short tags.